# No sound Ubuntu 20.04 Raspberry Pi

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, raspberrypi

I've recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 onto my Raspberry Pi. Its all working perfectly except for the sound. I can't get any sound whatsoever through hdmi, jack or bluetooth. When i try music on Youtube it won't play and says "If playback doesn't  resume shortly, try restarting your device".

I'm fairly certain it's not the speakers or the actual raspberry pi as i've tested both with alternative inputs/os's.

I have a feeling that it might be something to do with pulseaudio as i've had recent problems with that and the latest Rasbian update - https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/118961/how-to-fix-audio-after-december-2020-update - I've tried removing  pulseaudio but that didn't help.

Is there anything else i could try to fix this? Are there any other background systems that could be causing the problem?

Comment: You mentioned raspbian updates but Raspbian (Raspberry Pi OS) ≠ Ubuntu.  Which OS are you using?  If you are using Ubuntu, are you using the preinstalled image for Raspberry Pi?  Because all of the hardware should work properly for that image since it's made specifically for raspi hardware.

Comment: I was referring to my previous issue with Rasbian. This is an issue with Ubuntu that I flashed from the raspberry pi imager

Comment: I'm not familiar with the raspberry pi imager.  Are you certain that it uses the raspberry pi images that are published by Ubuntu?  See: https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi

Comment: Yes it’s made by the raspberry pi foundation who take the images direct from Ubuntu